# How to use ESC (&#27;) character in XML?

Tags: java, xml, dom, escaping, sax

I'm trying this:

```
<root>
  text: &#27;
</root>
```

But parser says:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 12; 
Character reference "&#27" is an invalid XML character.
  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
```

How to use it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot [( in XML 1.0)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets). In XML 1.1 there is a slightly larger range of characters you can use, and the [characters are expressed differently](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#charsets), but even then, `&#27;` is 'restricted' (hex it is `&#x1B;`) which, as far as I can tell, means that it is not valid XML, even though XML parsers should process it successfully. Note that the 'null' character (`&#x00;`) is never valid. Here's a [Wiki article on these characters in XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML)

You can try forcing the XML document to XML 1.1 and see if your parser will process it successfully.... set the first line of the XML to:

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>
```

In fact, I did that, and it works:

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>
<root>&#27;</root>
```

Comment: Wikipedia describes it as [restricted and highly discouraged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML#XML_1.1). As of 2015 I couldn't find a single item in my standard toolset that supports XML 1.1 at all.