# Conversion from Unicode to Original format into XML file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, utf-8, hex

Please let me know how to write a unicode`[ex: \u001B]` value into XML file as []escape symbol

I'm using UTF8 encoding and XMLWriter in C#, but it saves as "&#x1B ;" into XML

instead i want it to be written as "" escape symbol into XML.. 
Is this possible?

Thanks

Vinu

Comment: Your language is unclear.  Can you provide a [mcve] showing the XML that is currently generated, the c# code you use to generate it, and how you want to generate it instead?  See also [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Also, `\u001B` isn't a valid XML character in XML 1.0, which is what `XmlWriter` supports.  See [How to use ESC (&#27;) character in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18624510) and https://dotnetfiddle.net/XOCZVQ for confirmation.  We're going to need to see a demo of the problem to be much help I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode character x1B is not legal in XML 1.0; it cannot be present in an XML document with or without escaping.

In XML 1.1 it can be written as `&#x1B;`, but Microsoft's XML libraries do not support XML 1.1.